# handling dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I am reading a csv file using pandas and csv has date columns which is mixture of string and integers and ordered in ascending order, example shown below :

```
Date 
Dec 01 2010 
40513 
12/1/10 
12/1/10 9:00 
40513
```

Tried the below code to ignore values not as date ,

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], errors='coerce')

print(df.tail(20))
```

```
Date
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
NULL
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
NULL
```

I want to add  '30-12-1899' this date to the numbers , something like 
`df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime('30-12-1899') + pd.DateOffset(df['Date'])` and want my results to be :

```
Date
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
2010-12-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: How working my solution?

Comment: it works as expected, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Idea is convert datetimes to `Series` called `date`, then filter non parsed datetimes and add `DateOffset`, last use [`Series.combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.combine_first.html) or [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace missing values:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'],errors='coerce')
dates1 = (df.loc[dates.isna(), 'Date'].apply(lambda x: pd.DateOffset(days=int(x))) + 
                                                            pd.to_datetime('30-12-1899'))

df['Date'] = dates.combine_first(dates1)
print (df)
                 Date
0 2010-12-01 00:00:00
1 2010-12-01 00:00:00
2 2010-12-01 00:00:00
3 2010-12-01 09:00:00
4 2010-12-01 00:00:00
```